# Создание таблицы на html

Tags: html, css

Все привет!
Помогите разобраться, в чем причина: ниже код таблички, нужно чтобы вышло как на картинке, но не выходит. Кажется все перепробовал..( не пойму в чем причина..(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }
td{
  background-color: #000;
}

section-first table{
  width: 750px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #FAEBD7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
     <section-first>
                  <table cellspacing=20>
             <tr>
                 <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td rowspan="2"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td rowspan="2"></td>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td colspan="2"></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td colspan="2"></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </section-first>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: задайте для первого `td` , который `<td rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td>` ширину и всё.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:596px; width:596px;">4</td>
    <td style="height:288px; width:288px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:288px; width:288px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="height:288px; width:288px;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:596px; width:288px;">2 столбик</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2">2 столбик</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="height:288px; width:596px;">2 строка</td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">2 строка</td>
</tr>
```

Прошу прощения за грязный код. Не стал прикреплять стили. Должно работать